Integrating RTK Query with MSAL React
In our application we are using MSAL React and RTK Query.
MSAL React makes available a hook, through which you can access your access token.
We need to include that access token in our Authorization header.
I am struggling to understand the best way to access the access token if this is only accessible through the hook, as you cannot invoke hooks in RTK Query's prepareHeaders.
For the sake of sharing some code:
export const dataService = createApi({
  reducerPath: "DataService",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_API_GATEWAY_BASE_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, api) => {
      const { accessToken } = useMSAL(); // <-- React Hook "useCustomAuthHook" is called in function "prepareHeaders" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getDataUrl: builder.query<string, void>({
      query: () => ({ url: "api/v1/Data", method: "GET" }),
    }),
  }),
});

Other approaches we've considered:

Essentially creating a wrapper hook that wraps both the hook from MSAL as well as the RTK Query one, to prepare data before dispatching the query. But these feels like an anti-pattern.
Storing just the access token in state, such that we can use the api.getState() to fetch it


"Storing just the access token in state, such that we can use the api.getState() to fetch it" seems valid.  Where/how do you create the MSL instance the app is being provided and is using? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the Redux and MSAL setup/configuration code/logic you are using?
